# Azure KeyVaultErrorException on getKey

Tags: java, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm running AzureClient java sdk. I create keyvault client like this:

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials applicationTokenCredentials=new 
ApplicationTokenCredentials(APPLICATION_ID, "DOMAIN", CLIENT_SECRET, 
AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
vc = new KeyVaultClient(applicationTokenCredentials);
```

And the i write this code to get key from azure directory:

```
Future<KeyBundle> keyBundleFuture = vc.getKeyAsync(testKeyIdentifier, new ServiceCallback<KeyBundle>() {
    public void failure(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    public void success(KeyBundle keyBundle) {
        System.out.print(keyBundle.toString());
    }
});
KeyBundle keyBundle = keyBundleFuture.get();
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyVaultErrorException: Status code 401.
```

Also to note that I have given permissions to my applocation from azure portal to access keyvault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the status code `401` of your error and the REST API reference [`Authentication, requests, and responses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/authentication--requests-and-responses) of Key Vault, it was caused by using incorrect credentials with Azure Java SDK. To access Key Vault using Azure SDK must be authenticated with [`KeyVaultCredentials`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/authentication/KeyVaultCredentials.html) which need to be implemented the method [`doAuthenticate`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/keyvault/authentication/KeyVaultCredentials.html#doAuthenticate-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

As reference, here is my sample code below.

```
ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new KeyVaultCredentials() {

    @Override
    public String doAuthenticate(String authorization, String resource, String scope) {
        AuthenticationResult res = null;

        try {
            res = GetAccessToken(authorization, resource, clientId, secret);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return res.getAccessToken();
    }

    private AuthenticationResult GetAccessToken(String authorization, String resource, String clientID, String clientKey)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        AuthenticationContext ctx = null;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        try {
            ctx = new AuthenticationContext(authorization, false, service);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Future<AuthenticationResult> resp = ctx.acquireToken(resource, new ClientCredential(
            clientID, clientKey), null);
            AuthenticationResult res = resp.get();
            return res;
        }

    };
KeyVaultClient client = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
String keyIdentifier = "https://<your-keyvault>.vault.azure.net/keys/<your-key>/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
KeyBundle keyBundle = client.getKey(keyIdentifier);
```

Then, it works.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job